# cannot import name 'Dataset' from 'mlflow.entities'

Tags: python, azure, mlflow

I created pipeline with components in Azure ML Studio (SDK2).
When i run - i have a problem with package

```
 File "com_row_to_col.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mlflow
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import mlflow.tracking._model_registry.fluent
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mlflow.tracking.client import MlflowClient
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 28, in <module>
    from mlflow.tracking._tracking_service.client import TrackingServiceClient
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 20, in <module>
    from mlflow.store.artifact.artifact_repository_registry import get_artifact_repository
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repository_registry.py", line 13, in <module>
    from mlflow.store.artifact.s3_artifact_repo import S3ArtifactRepository
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/s3_artifact_repo.py", line 9, in <module>
    from mlflow import data
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/data/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mlflow.data import dataset_registry
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/data/dataset_registry.py", line 9, in <module>
    from mlflow.data.dataset import Dataset
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/data/dataset.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mlflow.entities import Dataset as DatasetEntity
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dataset' from 'mlflow.entities' (/azureml-envs/azureml_8fb4117f349a5533cb16993c2e87af3c/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/entities/__init__.py)
```

This error is 6 line

```
import mlflow
```

in component script...

I use env (i created)

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - numpy=1.21.2
  - pip=21.2.4
  - scikit-learn=0.24.2
  - scipy=1.7.1
  - 'pandas>=1.1,<1.2'
  - pip:
      - 'inference-schema[numpy-support]==1.3.0'
      - xlrd==2.0.1
      - mlflow==1.26.1
      - azureml-mlflow==1.42.0
      - 'psutil>=5.8,<5.9'
      - 'tqdm>=4.59,<4.60'
      - ipykernel~=6.0
      - matplotlib
name: model-env
```

Its important... Early i worked with sample from github (official) and worked...

Any idea?
I tried remove compute, remove env.... change env version mlflow...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information, you are using mlfow version=1.26.1
[image]
It's seems the dataset class is not available in this specific version.

To fix this you can try later version with dataset class available in `mlfow.entitites`.

You can try the `mlflow version 2.6.0`.
[image]
**Note:** Make sure to check the compatibility of the `mlflow` package with your other dependencies and Python version.